# jackson - map nested objects as list with self reference

Tags: xml, jackson, jaxb

I want to map below XML with Jackson Object.

```
<field source="condition" target="transaction.transactionType">
    <ifConditions>
        <ifCondition operand="isShortSell" operator="eq" expectedValue="true">      <!-- This is available after tranformation> -->
            <ifCondition operand="quanity" operator="gt" expectedValue="0" />       <!-- This is NOT available after tranformation> -->
                open
            </ifCondition>
        </ifCondition>
        <ifCondition operand="isShortSell" operator="eq" expectedValue="true">      <!-- This is available after tranformation> -->
            <ifCondition operand="quanity" operator="lt" expectedValue="0" />       <!-- This is NOT available after tranformation> -->
                close
            </ifCondition>
        </ifCondition>
     </ifConditions>
</field>
```

Below is my current mapping. The current issue i am facing is I am not able to get any of the nested IfCondition objects.

How do i transform nested objects, there can be N level of nesting. Am i missing any annotation ?

```
public class Field implements Serializable {

    private String source;

    @JsonProperty("source-type")
    private String sourceType;

    private String target;

    @JsonProperty("target-type")
    private String targetType;

    @JsonProperty("allow-null")
    private boolean allowNull;

    @JsonProperty("default-value")
    private String defaultValue;

    @JsonProperty("external-mapping")
    private String externalMapping;

    private String pattern;

    private List<IfCondition> ifConditions;

}


@XmlRootElement
public class IfCondition implements Serializable {

    private String expectedValue;

    @XmlElement
    private String value;

    private String operand;

    private String operator;

    private List<IfCondition> ifCondition;

}
```

Am i missing any annotation?

Comment: Your XML example isn't correct (I get syntax errors because of unbalanced start and end tags)

Comment: @ThomasFritsch I've edited my original post with corrected XML structure.